# Calculate keras metric in numpy rather than tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, metrics

I'm trying to calculate a Keras metric in NumPy rather than in TensorFlow.

As you usually don't need the gradient flow through a pure metric, it would be fine to calculate the metric in NumPy.

I extended `tf.keras.metrics.Metrics` and have overwritten the `update_state()` method.
There, I get `y_true` and `y_pred` as type `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor` with shape `(None, 64, 64, 64, 6)`

Unfortunately, I can't convert the tensor to a NumPy array. I think because the metric gets precompiled and thus no values are available yet (that's why the first shape is None)?

I tried using `y_true.eval()`, `y_true.numpy()`, provided a session e.g., `y_true.eval(session=session)` with `session=tf.compat.v1.Session()` or `tf.compat.v1.get_default_session()` - none worked.

How can I calculate the metric in NumPy? Unfortunately, I can't just reimplement all NumPy functions using TensorFlow functions as I want to use a certain package.

I'm using `tensorflow 2.5, keras 2.4.3`

Answer (score 0):

wrap your function within `tf.py_function`

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function

Keras wants to build a graph beforehand, but NumPy requires the computation to be eager. `py_function` allows the computation to be done later when the actual values are available.